# Unable to update Mongoose array type field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to add some object id into array .Here is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    moment = require('moment-timezone');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var tag = new Schema({
    name: String,
    urlId: Array,
    createdOn : {
        type: Date,
        default: moment().tz('Asia/Dhaka')
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', tag);
```

and my router part where I am trying to update `urlId` field :

```
.post(function(req, res) {
        var url = new URL({title: req.body.title, href: req.body.url});
        url.save();
        Tag.findOne({name: req.body.tag}, function(err, hiren) {
           if(hiren) {
              Tag.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: hiren._id}, {$push: {urlId: url._id}}, {safe: true, upsert: true, new: true}); //this line is not working

           }
            else {
               var tag = new Tag({name: req.body.tag, urlId: url._id});
               tag.save();
           }
        });
```

Is this correct way to update `Array` type field or I am missing something

Comment: So what is the problem/error/unexpected result? Apart from you are being silly enough to try and force a `Date` object into a local timezone storage which shows you are just not conprehending how to scale your application globally. And of course that you are horribly ingoring the need to acknowledge callbacks.

Comment: `Tag.findByIdAndUpdate` is not working, `$push` didn't push new object id to the  `urlId` array . By the way I tried to use callback, but it didn't throw any error.

Comment: Why would you even call `.findByIdAndUpdate()` when you don't use a callback to get the result? You say "it didn't push" but how do you know? You never check the result and there is no reason why it should not. And not to mention that the whole process should have used `.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": req.body.tag }, { "$push": { "urlId": url._id } },{ "new": true, "upsert": true },function(err,doc) { console.log(doc) })` in the first place as it already does everything you are trying to code in an `if..else` condition. And correctly.

Comment: If it "doesn't work" then it's because the `{ "name": req.body.tag }` does not match anything. So check your inputs. Log them. And you will clearly see what you are doing wrong.